# Why does Linked questions allow anyone to see some details of a deleted post without checking their privileges?

Tags: support, privileges, linked-questions

Take for example the question (on Drupal.SE) about "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212520)". It is deleted and in its ***Linked*** block (to the right, above its "Related" block) it shows 2 other questions. Users on that site with less than 10k reputation, or without a diamond, or not the author of the question (who happens to be me) only see a friendly "Page Not Found" message, which is all good.

However, by manually changing the URL to the [***Linked questions*** view of the question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/212520/), any user can see it. Even with less than 10k reputation, even totally anonymous visitors. This is showing at least:

- the title of the deleted question.
- the title of the questions linked to the deleted question.

Why does Linked questions allow anyone to see some details of the deleted post without checking their privileges? That does not seem to be the case for  these variations for that same question:

- The [timeline](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/212520/timeline) page.
- The [revisions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/212520/revisions) page.

*Note*: for deleted questions with 0 linked questions (such as this [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/208299/)), a similar ***Linked questions*** URL also reveals the title of the deleted question.

Comment: What's wrong with telling them the title, exactly? It's already in the URL when trying to access the deleted question so they're not exactly getting any new information... Not saying this doesn't need to be fixed if not just to be consistent, but your reasoning doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @animuson If this is not to be considered as "wrong", then why does the question title of that deleted question no longer show up (automatically), if you linked to such deleted question from another question (which is not deleted). I'd be happy to retag my question to "discussion" (instead of bug) as per your prior comment, but if the outcome is that it's OK to still show the title, then in the linked questions such title should still be shown also (which is not the case right now).

Comment: I'm just saying that you're making a big deal over revealing something that is *already revealed* by the URL you used to get to the question in the first place. Why not focus on just being consistent?

Comment: As per @animuson 's "big deal" comment, I'm fine with considering it a support question. Hence my revision of my question.

Comment: I don't really care in the least that someone can see the title of a deleted question.  It *is* concerning however that a deleted question is shown in the linked section.  I can't see how that'd be useful, unless it's only there because it's recently deleted and this is just a caching issue.

Comment: @Servy both question samples were deleted long time (months) ago, so I don't think it has anything to do with caching.

Comment: @Servy: Nobody can necessarily see *other deleted questions* in the list. Neither example displays that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see any issue with this. It doesn't really reveal any new information. If a < 10k user visits, e.g.:

```
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212520
```

You'll already see the title as the URL will be replaced with:

```
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212520/how-to-process-the-results-of-a-vbo-enabled-view-via-rules
```

Also, there's nothing you can really *do* with this information. There's no real consequences.

As for the linked questions, that doesn't seem to be an issue. They're just questions. If they themselves aren't deleted there's no reason to hide them.